# A ide Eclipse parou de reclamar a necessidade de declarar o serial default Version ID. nas classes serializadas

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Olá, utilizando a IDE Eclipse quando criamos uma classe que informamos que ela deve implementar a serialização (implements Serializable) é comum a IDE reclamar o default serial Version Id.

Criei um projeto novo na IDE e quase tudo funcionando normalmente na ide, porém ao criar uma nova classe e implementar a serialização, a Ide não sinaliza mais a necessidade de criar o valor default.

Alguém sabe como habilitar para que na ide que ela informe a a necessidade de criação do valor default igual a figura abaixo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vá em Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Erros/Warnings -> Potential Programing Problems. Depois basta localizar a opção "Serializable class without serialVersionUID" e selecionar "Warning".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá Felipe, imaginei que fosse isso mas ao acessar a configuração ela já esta desta forma. O engraçado é que só este projeto esta assim, os demais esta funcionando.

Comment: @JoséLuizGonzagaNeto Verifique se o projeto está utilizando configurações especificas para ele. Clique com o botão direito sobre projeto, vá em: Propriedades -> Java Compiler -> Errors/Warnings. Caso não esteja, tente clicar com o botão direito sobre o projeto e depois em "Validate"

Comment: Valeu Felipe, acho que deve ter sido algum problema na IDE, criei um novo projeto e migrei os arquivos. Abraços.